How to enforce loading all image on web page immediately at loading time ("eager" not working)?
Occasionally I visit a web page with embedded images.
Now I want to print it (into pdf file).
Unfortunately it is not printed with ALL the containing images.
I have first to scroll down to the bottom of the web page to tell the browser to request all images step by step from server and fill it into image places.
I consider to write a user.js script and put some javascript/jquery/css commands inside to enforced immediate loading after web page load.
But my first idea simply adding the CSS property
img { loading: "eager" !important; }

does not work. It seems that the delayed loading is not because of a lazy loading but determined by a script. This script monitors if the user is scrolling down the web page.
Hmm, any suggestion to enforced immediate loading WITHOUT SCROLLING?
Do you need an example webpage?
Here is one:
https://www.wintips.org/how-to-disable-device-encryption-in-windows-11/
Obviously I have no access to the server but are only a user on a Chrome browser client.

You need to scroll to bottom of the page before saving. That should be enough and the only way

Would writing a script to fetch each image and replace the src with a dataURL work? I've not tested it. Just an idea.

On the page in question, load the page and change the src of all images that have [data-src] with the content of that data-src before saving

You have a script which listens to a scroll event and once it happens (the user scrolled "down" enough), then triggers a function, let's call this function f for the sake of this answer.
So it might look like this:
document.addEventListener("scroll", function (event) {
    var lastDiv = document.querySelector("#scroll-content > div:last-child");
    var lastDivOffset = lastDiv.offsetTop + lastDiv.clientHeight;
    var pageOffset = window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight;

    if(pageOffset > lastDivOffset - 20) {    
        f();
    }
});

and f is to send a request to the server and once the answer is received, then it is to write some HTML into a container.
However, requests are not instant and you want to improve upon UX. Therefore, you could do the following:
let cached = undefined;
function f() {
    if (cached) {
        //If we have some preloaded data, then we write it into the container, so it will appear to work instantly
        writeCached(cached);
    }
    load(); //this sends a request to the server and when it is being responded, writes it to cached
}

So,  essentially whenever you scroll down, you write the preloaded items into the container and load the next chunk, so by the time the user scrolls down the next chunk will be ready and so on.
However, this means that you always rely on the items preloaded and hence, you need to trigger f on page load, so at the first scroll you will have something ready as well, via:
window.addEventListener("load", f);

